# "The Dataflow appears to be stuck" on Cloud Dataflow with Apache Beam 2.1.1 after switching to Firebase Firestore as a pipeline source

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling with this, and initially thought it could be the result of switching the pipeline data source from Cloud Datastore to Firebase Firestore, which required a new project. But I've since found the same error in separate pipelines. All pipelines run successfully on the local DirectRunner and the permissions appear to be the same as the old project.

It looks like none of the VMs are booting and the pipeline never scales above 0 workers. "The Dataflow appears to be stuck" is the only error message I could find and there is nothing in StackDriver. Tried every dependency management variation I could find in the docs but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

My last Dataflow job-id is 2017-10-11_11_12_01-15165703816317931044.

Tried elevating the access roles of all services accounts and still no luck.

Comment: Are there any errors in the StackDriver worker logs for this job?

Comment: No, I couldn't find any. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any logging information, it's hard to pinpoint. But this can happen if you have changed the permissions or roles of the Dataflow service account or the Compute Engine service account so that the service account does not have enough permissions to get the images for the Dataflow workers.

Comment: For more info: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#compute-engine-service-account

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. I have tried elevating the compute and dataflow service accounts to editor/owner but it hasn't changed. I do think you are on to something though because I moved to a new project to use Firebase Firestore as a data source.

Comment: So it turned out the Dataflow API wasn't enabled in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library. Which was strange because I had access to the Dataflow dashboard in the console, and never received an error which the similar StackOverflow questions suggested. Thanks for your help David.

Comment: Glad that you have this fixed. But it's still strange since if you had not enabled the Dataflow API, you wouldn't even have the dataflow service account in the project...